# how to expand template parameter pack to series of templated arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have this simple template class:

```
template<typename T>
class property
{
    // ...
};
```

and this variadic template class:

```
template<typename... factory_args>
class type_t
{
    // …
```

and in this class I would like to have a constructor that gets expanded to this:

```
    type_t (property<first_type>&, property<second_type>& etc.)
```

where `first_type`, `second_type` etc. should come from `factory_args`.

I would then be able to call the constructor like this:

```
property<int> first = etc...;
property<void*> second = ...;
auto some_type = type_t<int, void*>(first, second);
```

Ideally, template argument deduction would work too so I could call it like this too:

```
auto some_other_type = type_t(first, second);
```

**How do I write the `type_t` constructor? Is this doable in C++17?**

Comment: `type_t(property<factory_args> &... args)`? Or do you want multiple named arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
template<typename... factory_args>
class type_t
{
public:
    type_t(property<factory_args>&... args);
};
```

Class Template Argument Deduction does the right thing here too. So if you had:

```
property<int> i;
property<void*> v;
type_t x(i, v); // ok, x is a type_t<int, void*>
```